# What do you mean by the caller of a method in Java?

Tags: java, terminology

I am confused about what a caller of a method menans in Java. Can someone clarify that with an example?

Comment: "caller" means the code which calls the method.  What is your doubt?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is referring to the method that is calling the other method.

```
public void foo() {
  bar();
}

public void bar() {
   // foo could be the caller of bar here.
}
```

In general, if you look in your stacktrace, each two consecutive lines A and B basically mean »A is called by B« or »B is the caller of A«.

Answer (score 1):

See the following example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("hello, world");
}
```

Method main() is the caller of `println()`

Answer (score 1):

Some code is calling the method. That would be the caller.

Example:

```
public class A {
   public static void main(String[] argv) {
       System.out.println("Hello");
   }
}
```

Here, the method `println` is called by `A#main` (method `main` in class `A`).